# Obtener un parametro por medio de un querystring

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Al pasar de una pagina a otra envio por medio de un querystring el parametro usuario, al estar en la pagina nueva veo que la url tiene el valor que me estoy trayendo (usuario) pero, no se como obtener ese valor estando en la nueva pagina.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dim usr As String = Request.QueryString("usuario")`